# awk : set start and end of match

Tags: regex, awk

I have a LaTeX-like table like this (columns are delimited by `&`) :

```
foobar99   &     68 
foobar4    &     43 
foobar2    &     73
```

I want to get the index of the numbers at column 2 by using `match`.

In Vim, we can use `\zs` and `\ze` to set start and end of matching.
Thus, to match accurately number at colum 2, we can use `^.*&\s*\zs[[:digit:]]\+\ze\s*$`.

How about awk? Is there an equivalent?

EDIT:

Matching for the first line:

```
foobar99   &     68 
                 ^^   

123456789012345678
```

Expected output : `18`.

EDIT2:

I am writing an awk script to deal with block delimited by line break (Hence, `FS="\n"` and `RS=""`). The MWE above is just one of these blocks.

A possible way to get the index of number at column 2 is to do something like that

```
split(line, cases, "&");
index = match(cases[2], /[[:digit:]]\+/);
```

but I am looking for a beautiful way to do this.

Apologies for the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). But I'm still interested in start/end matching.

Comment: Please tell me why to downvote so that I can delete this question or do something.

Comment: I didn't downvote but: _get the index of the numbers at column 2_ Your sample does not have numbers in column 2. Also, post the expected output for that sample.

Comment: Column two? What delimiter you accounted for?

Comment: Just edited. I forgot to explain what is the delimiter...

Comment: You need indexes or the numbers?

Comment: Are you looking for the character numbers within the column at which the digits appear, or the value of the number in the column (or something else)?  What is your desired output for the given input?

Comment: If you're using FS `\n` and RS `""` then  your input must not look like the input you've provided for us in your example so it's like asking us for help fixing your car when you really own a horse. Update your question to provide a [mcve] with realistic concise, testable sample input and expected output or you'll be advised your horse needs a new transmission.

Answer (score 0):

Too little context, so a simple guess: have you tried splitting the table into columns? With something like `awk -F '\\s*&\\s*'` you have your second column in `$2`.

In fact, you can use `split()` to retrieve the exact column of a string:

```
split(s, a[, fs ])

Split  the  string  s into array elements a[1], a[2], ..., a[n], and 
return n.  All elements of the array shall be deleted before the split is 
performed. The separation shall be done with the ERE fs or with the field 
separator FS if fs is not given. Each array  element  shall  have  a  
string value  when  created  and,  if  appropriate, the array element 
shall be considered a numeric string (see Expressions in awk).  The 
effect of a null string as the value of fs is unspecified.
```

So your second column is something like

```
split(s, a, /\s*&\s*/)
secondColumn = a[2]
```

Comment: In fact, I am writing an awk script. `FS` is set to `\n`. In my case should I set it temporarily to `\\s*&\\s*` or use `split` then `match`? Just wondering if there is a more beautiful way to do this..

Comment: @FirminMartin Why do you set `FS` to `\n`? That should be `RS`.

Comment: @Barmar `RS` is set to `""`. I am working with block separated by line break.

Comment: @FirminMartin You need to post your code so that the context and constraints are clear in the question.

Comment: @Barmar Just edited. So, the central idea in awk is playing with the delimiter? Start/end matching doesn't exist?

Comment: @FirminMartin You can the `match()` function to match a regular expression, it sets variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` to indicate where the match is.

Comment: @FirminMartin Normally awk processes a line at a time using `RS` as the delimiter, then you can access fields using `FS` as the delimiter. When you make a whole block of lines a record, you need to do the line and field splitting yourself with functions like `split()`.

Comment: @FirminMartin Let's say it is somewhat simpler than to try create a single do-it-all regexp.

Comment: @Barmar I see. Since `FS` is set to `\n` in my case, I loop through `$i`. I didn't know `RSTART` before. My main question can be reformulated as "how to match a subset of regex ". Probably, this can be done by adjusting `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` in an extended `match` function.

Comment: @FirminMartin you are completely misunderstanding how awk works. When you edit your question to provide a real [mcve], also tell us if you are using GNU awk or some other version (`awk --version`).

Answer (score 0):

By default, `awk` sees three columns in your data, and column 2 contains `&` only (and column 3 contains numbers). If you change the field delimiter to `&`, then you have two columns with trailing spaces in column 1 and leading spaces in column 2 (and some trailing spaces, as it happens; try copying the data from the question).

In `awk`, you could convert column 2 with leading spaces into a number by adding `0`: `$2 + 0` would force it to be treated as a number.  If you use `$2` in a numeric context, it'll be treated as a number. Conversely, you can force `awk` to treat a field as a string by concatenating with the empty string: `$2 ""` will be a string.

So there's no need for the complexity of regexes to get at the number — if the data is as simple as shown.

You say you want to use `match`; it is not clear what you need that for.

```
awk -F'&' '{ printf "F1 [%s], F2 [%10s] = [%d] = [%-6d] = [%06d]\n", $1, $2, $2, $2, $2 }' data
```

For your data, which has a single blank at the end of the first two lines and a double blank at the end of the third, the output is:

```
F1 [foobar99   ], F2 [       68 ] = [68] = [68    ] = [000068]
F1 [foobar4    ], F2 [       43 ] = [43] = [43    ] = [000043]
F1 [foobar2    ], F2 [      73  ] = [73] = [73    ] = [000073]
```

Note that I didn't need to explicitly convert `$2` to a number.  The `printf` formats treated it as a string or a number depending on whether I used `%s` or `%d`.

If you need to, you can strip trailing blanks of `$1` (or, indeed, `$2`), but without knowing what else you need to do, it's hard to demonstrate alternatives usefully.

So, I think `awk` does what you need without needing you to jump through much in the way of hoops.  For a better explanation, you'd need to provide a better question, describing or showing what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
awk '{print index($0,$3)}' infile
```